# C# - WCF cannot find endpoints on windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, endpoint

I have a windows service and a form, and I need them to communicate. Every sites I visited point to WCF. I tried to implemented it on the service first. Like this:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        event_log.WriteEntry("TOPIAM_ADM: start");
        timer.Start();
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    }
```

That's the only line that related with the WCF. When I start the service, it gave me this error

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Config...

I looked up for hours, but still no clue on how should i get the config file right.

The WCF has its own project, service has another, and that windows form app has another project. I'm pretty sure it's from config file. Anyone can help me out?

Service project's config:

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>
>   <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" />   </system.web>   <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be
> added to the host's    app.config file. System.Configuration does not
> support config files for libraries. -->   <system.serviceModel>
>     <bindings>
>       <basicHttpBinding>
>         <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
>       </basicHttpBinding>
>     </bindings>
>     <client>
>       <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/TOPIAM_WCFLibrary/Service1/"
>         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
>         contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
>     </client>
>     <behaviors>
>       <serviceBehaviors>
>         <behavior>
>           <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
>           set the value below to false before deployment -->
>           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
>           <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
>           set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
>           to avoid disclosing exception information -->
>           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
>         </behavior>
>       </serviceBehaviors>
>     </behaviors>   </system.serviceModel>
> 
> </configuration>
```

WCF project's config

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>
>   <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" />   </system.web>   <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be
> added to the host's    app.config file. System.Configuration does not
> support config files for libraries. -->   <system.serviceModel>
>     <services>
>       <service name="TOPIAM_WCFLibrary.Service1">
>         <host>
>           <baseAddresses>
>             <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/TOPIAM_WCFLibrary/Service1/"
> />
>           </baseAddresses>
>         </host>
>         <!-- Service Endpoints -->
>         <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
>         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TOPIAM_WCFLibrary.IService1">
>           <!-- 
>               Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
>               identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
>               automatically.
>           -->
>           <identity>
>             <dns value="localhost"/>
>           </identity>
>         </endpoint>
>         <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
>         <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
>         <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
>         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
>       </service>
>     </services>
>     <behaviors>
>       <serviceBehaviors>
>         <behavior>
>           <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
>           set the value below to false before deployment -->
>           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
>           <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
>           set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
>           to avoid disclosing exception information -->
>           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
>         </behavior>
>       </serviceBehaviors>
>     </behaviors>   </system.serviceModel>
> 
> </configuration>
```

Anyone can point out where I put it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your config file with service settings into startup WinForms application project.